# hidapi on windows - undefined reference to functions

Tags: c, eclipse, usb, hid, hidapi

I build the hidapi on windows using Visual Studios. The build generated a 'hidapi.lib' file. Now I am trying to write C code using Eclipse IDE and have included the 'hidapi.lib' by changing it's name to 'libhid.lib'. The hidapi.h is also present and included. The error comes when I try to access any of the functions of the hidapi.h
The compiler gives an undefined reference error everytime I run the program. Where am  Igoing wrong ?

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhziA.jpg)
[compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXlSm.jpg)

```
/* ============================================================‌​
Name : hid_attemp1.c 
Author : Shantanu 
Version : 
Copyright : Your copyright notice 
Description : Hello World in C, Ansi-style 
============================================================‌​===*/ 
#ifdef WIN32 
#include <windows.h> 
#endif 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "hidapi.h" 
int main(void) { 
    int r; 
    r = hid_init(); 
    if(r<0) 
        printf("error in init()\n"); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: Can you paste code into your answer, rather than including screenshots, please?

Comment: Mixing binaries from GCC and MSVC sometimes does not work, especially in the case of static libraries.  Can you compile both HIDAPI and your program using a single toolchain?

Comment: The hidapi repository I downloaded from Github contains a .sln project which can be build using only MS VS.

Comment: https://github.com/signal11/hidapi - this is the Git repository I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a C project on visual studio, included the hidapi.h and linked the hidapi.lib to the project. The project build successfully and I was able to run it. As far as I am concerned, the problem is the incompatibility of the 'hidapi.lib' between the Visual Studio and Eclipse IDE.